# WKSelectionGranularityCharacter option of WKWebView broken in iOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9, wkwebview

I have an iPad app that uses the `WKSelectionGranularityCharacter` option of a `WKWebView`. It worked fine on an iOS 8 device and works on an 8.4 simulator but is broken on 9.1. A long press on text shows the magnifier but upon release no text is highlighted nor do any selection handles appear.

Is anyone else seeing this changed/broken behavior? Is there a workaround?

**Update 10/31/2015**: Also fails on XCode 7.2 and iOS 9.2 beta.  Reported to Apple as a bug.

**Update 11/26/2015**: Still broken in latest XCode.  No response or even a ranking at Apple's bugreport site.