# The bug when use WKWebViewConfiguration to set the property selectionGranularity to .Character will get no text selection view

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, textselection, wkwebviewconfiguration

This is my setting for WKWebView:

```
func setupWebView() -> WKWebView {
    let configutation = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configutation.selectionGranularity = .Character
    
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height),
                              configuration: configutation)
    
    view.addSubview(webView)
    return webView
}
```

Then used lazy to get:

```
lazy var webView: WKWebView = self.setupWebView()
```

> Both the same problem in Device or Simulator:

[image]

> Setting the property to .Dynamic seem works well.

[image]

> But I don't want the Selection style.

[image]

> Does anyone know how to solve problem?
>
> Thanks a lot!

Comment: I fixed it, can you help me? @JAL

Comment: Seems duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429158/wkselectiongranularitycharacter-option-of-wkwebview-broken-in-ios-9

Answer (score 0):

Known bug, you might want to report it once more to raise it's priority: http://www.openradar.me/23345435